# Python <No such file or directory: 'gs'> error even with GhostScript installed on Macintosh *Issue still Persisting!*

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, save, ghostscript

I have implemented the following save function in my program which allows the user to save as a JPEG file whatever he/she draws on the Tkinter canvas with the Turtle. How it is supposed to work is that it first captures the screen and Tkinter canvas and then creates a postscript file based on it. Then it converts that postscript file as a PIL (Python Imaging Library) readable file type, and then the PIL saves the converted file as a JPEG. My save function is shown below:

```
def savefirst(): 
    # Capture screen and Tkinter canvas
    cnv = getscreen().getcanvas() 
    global hen
    # Save screen and canvas as Postscript file
    ps = cnv.postscript(colormode = 'color')
    # Open a Tkinter file dialog that allows to input his.her own name for the file
    hen = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension = '.jpg')
    # Convert Postscript file to PIL readable format
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))
    # Finally save converted file as a JPEG
    im.save(hen + '.jpg')
```

However, whenever I run this save function, I get the error shown below:

```
line 2396, in savefirst
    im.save(hen + '.jpg')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1646, in save
    self.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 337, in load
    self.im = Ghostscript(self.tile, self.size, self.fp, scale)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 143, in Ghostscript
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1544, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs'
```

even though I already have GhostScript installed! I know this because I first installed it through the Disk Image located [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/) and ran the installer. However, since that did not work, I then did this in **Terminal**:

```
`pip install ghostscript`
```

and since even that did not work, I then ran this in Terminal:

```
`conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/mlgill ghostscript`
```

**I used *3 ways* to install GhostScript and still keep getting the same error. Why is that and how else would I solve this issue?**

FYI: Just in case you need to know, my operating system is Mac OS 10.11.2 and my Python version is 3.5.1

**EDIT:** So, as a comment once said, try to solve this using Homebrew. So, naturally I installed it (since I did not have Homebrew already installed). Then, upon successful installation, I ran `brew install ghostscript`. After a few kinks I solved, I was able to successfully install GhostScript (well, according to Homebrew anyways). Then I ran `brew doctor` and found out it was unlinked! ****Gasp**** Well, a fix is easy enough, just link it! So, that is just what I did, and after fixing a few other kinks, I was finally able to successfully execute `brew link ghostscript`. However, despite my heroic, bodacious attempts at fixing the error, it remained... Yep, despite my best efforts, the error in IDLE when I run my save function **still occurs!** Additionally, running `gs` in Terminal returns:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/bin/gs
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

**What is STILL going wrong? Why can't Python (or even Terminal) find `gs`?**

**EDIT # 2:** Okay, so I have finally been able to install GhostScript **using Homebrew**. All I had to do was install xQuarts, which GhostScript apparently needs. HOWEVER, **my initial issue is STILL not fixed!** `gs` now works in Terminal:

```
:~ #######$ gs
GPL Ghostscript 9.18 (2015-10-05)
Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
```

But my **save function** STILL does not work in Python, and now I am SURE I have GhostScript installed! I still keep on getting this error in IDLE whenever I run my save function:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs'
```

**What is still going wrong?**

**EDIT # 3:** [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_2bdLwzG0cHUXF5WmRFRVF1MGc/view?usp=sharing) is my Python script, just in case it is needed.

-***EDIT # 4 Removed***-

**EDIT # 5:** I have a small hunch this is important, so I am putting it out there. Whenever I run `brew doctor` in Terminal, I get warnings that are not important, but this one stands out to me for some reason. I really don't know why, but anyways, here it is:

```
Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.
```

Maybe this is what is causing my issues? If so, how would I fix it?

**EDIT # 6:** Apparently it works for others (both windows AND Mac), but still NOT FOR ME! I STILL keep on getting this error whenever I run my program's `savefirst()` function:

```
line 2395, in savefirst
    im.save(hen + '.jpg')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1646, in save
    self.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 337, in load
    self.im = Ghostscript(self.tile, self.size, self.fp, scale)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 143, in Ghostscript
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1544, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs'
```

It's REALLY weird because `gs` WORKS in Terminal AND this:

```
x=subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/gs', '--version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(x.stdout.read())
```

works in Python IDLE. But for some reason, Python Imaging Library (PIL) still **CANNOT** detect `gs` (maybe because of its subprocess.Popen() function?). Why is that? **I have xQuarts, GhostScript, and PIL all installed on my Macintosh**, but I **still get the error when I run my `savefirst()` function! *Why?***

**P.S. This is all occuring on Macintosh (OS 10.11.2), so answers from those proficient with Macintosh are preferred!**

-***EDIT # 7 Removed***-

**EDIT # 8:** Okay, I have finally been able to PERMANENTLY (hopefully...) add `/usr/local/bin/gs` to my PATH (as you can see below):

```
Library/usr/local/bin/gs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin://anaconda/bin:/Users/Rohan/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

I added that path by running `pico ~MyName/.bash_profile` and then entering:

```
PATH="Library/usr/local/bin/gs:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

into the `/.bash.profile` file. However, I STILL keep getting that `FileNotFoundError` in Python! Did I append `/usr/local/bin/gs` to my PATH the wrong way, or even in the wrong directory? **If that is not the case, then *why can't the Python Imaging Library STILL find `gs`??***

**EDIT # 9:** Hurrah! Issue RESOLVED! The error does NOT appear anymore. All I had to do was REMOVE `/usr/local/bin/gs` from my Mac Path, and apparently add it instead to my PYTHONPATH, like so at the beginning of my program:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += ":/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/gs"
```

Huzzah! It works! PIL can now find `gs`, and can save the canvas as  JPEG, although it is in a very low resolution, but that is an issue for another question. For now, I am just glad the initial issue is resolved and I can finally save the canvas as a JPEG (Thanks to @Copperfield!) :)

Comment: You need to install ghostscript, not the python library for ghostscript. Open a terminal a type `gs` and hit the enter key, do you get an error message?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes I do. I get this error: `dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/bin/gs
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Comment: So that's your problem - `gs` is not installed correctly on your system.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid So how would I install it correctly?

Comment: `brew install ghostscript`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I get the error: `-bash: brew: command not found`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I did all that (installed Homebrew and ran the `brew install ghostscript` command) and that same error STILL occurs in Python IDLE and I still get the same error in terminal when I type `gs`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I just ran `brew install gs` again in Terminal, and I get this warning: `Warning: ghostscript-9.18 already installed, it's just not linked`.

Comment: @R.Kap
So have you tried 
brew link ghostscript-9.18

Comment: @Akki I have already linked GhostScript, but the error still occurs

Comment: Is this an X11 issue? try install http://www.xquartz.org

Comment: Your `PATH="Library/usr/local/bin/gs:${PATH}"` line doesn't look right: I think that should be `PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"`. (Items in the `PATH` should refer to directories, not files). Also, what happens when you run `which gs` in the terminal?

Comment: I'm also hanging out in your [chat room that you were in earlier](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100721/discussion-between-copperfield-and-r-kap) if you want to talk there.

Comment: @rmunn Are you still there? I sent you a message in the chat room.

Comment: @rmunn I also tried what you told me to (i.e. change `PATH="Library/usr/local/bin/gs:${PATH}"` to `PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"`), but I still keep on getting the same error in Python.

Comment: After you make that change in your `.bash_profile`, try typing "set | grep PATH" and see if it has taken effect. (If you haven't logged out and logged back in, then it might not have taken effect yet.) Then try again to run `python3` and do `shutil.which("gs")`. Also do `print(os.environ("PATH"))` and see what that gives you.

Comment: Glad you fixed it! A couple more things you should know. 1) `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` are not the same thing. `PATH` is the set of directories where the OS (and Python) will look for **executable** files, like `gs`. `PYTHONPATH` is the set of directories where Python will look for **importable** modules. When you use `subprocess.Popen()`, the `PATH` is what gets searched for the program you want. When you use `import modulename`, the `PYTHONPATH` is what gets searched for the module you want.

Comment: And 2) you shouldn't put filenames in your `PATH`; they'll just clutter it up uselessly. `PATH` is a list of *directories*, not files. So your `os.environ["PATH"] += ":/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/gs"` line should just be `os.environ["PATH"] += ":/usr/local/bin"`. Try that, and you'll see that it works exactly the same: the `/usr/local/bin/gs` entry was just cluttering the thing up to no benefit.

Comment: @rmunn Thanks for the input! Yup, you are right, it works. Now, are you experienced with PIL in any way? If so, could you please check out this question? > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821534/python-imaging-library-jpeg-conversion-outputs-tkinter-canvas-with-issues <

Comment: Sorry, no real experience with PIL. I'll have to let other people answer your new question.

Comment: Dude this is literally exactly what I told you to do. And I didn't even get an upvote smh....

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/p8jnzmw2p/

Comment: I have the same problem on OS-X El Capitan (10.11.6). Although, I was trying to install Ghostscript in a virtual environment so my Paths are a little bit different. Additionally, now that I realize I need a program called 'gs' and not a Python module called ghostscript I have started trying to install ghostscript from brew. Brew tells me my mac is old and they are not responsible for anything. yikes. Seems like there would be a simpler way to save an image...Like casting to an object then saving. Thanks for posting your question. I was surprised to find someone else ran into this issue. #_0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a idea: checking in the [code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py) of PIL, it use the [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil.which#shutil.which) module to find `gs` doing `shutil.which("gs")` maybe you need to modify some environment variable until until that work?

**EDIT**

talking in the chat room, we find what appear to be the problem, and that is [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess.popen#subprocess.Popen) can't find `gs`, but we got stuck there. Any ideas??

**EDIT 2**

I found a posible solution, first I remove `gs` from my path, and I try this

```
>>> import os,shutil,subprocess
>>> shutil.which("gswin64c") # shutil.which("gs")
>>> test = subprocess.Popen(["gswin64c","--version"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE) # subprocess.Popen(["gs","--version"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    test = subprocess.Popen(["gswin64c","--version"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
>>> os.environ["PATH"]
'C:\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Anaconda3;C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Haskell\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Haskell Platform\\2013.2.0.0\\lib\\extralibs\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Haskell Platform\\2013.2.0.0\\bin;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\;C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2009a\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2009a\\bin\\win64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Haskell Platform\\2013.2.0.0\\mingw\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\;C:\\Anaconda3;C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Roaming\\cabal\\bin;C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin;C:\\Users\\David\\Dropbox\\Programas Random'
>>> os.environ["PATH"] += ";C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.18\\bin"
>>> shutil.which("gswin64c")
'C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.18\\bin\\gswin64c.EXE'
>>> test = subprocess.Popen(["gswin64c","--version"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> test.stdout.read()
b'9.18\n'
>>>
```

to make this work with your code the following changes I made:

```
#this is very first import
import os
print("## Addind gs to environ ##", os.environ["PATH"] )
os.environ["PATH"] += ";C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.18\\bin"
print("## Addind gs to environ ##", os.environ["PATH"] )

#then the others import, and everything else
```

and testing it work fine.

In your case that maybe is:

```
#this is very first import
import os
print("## Addind gs to environ ##", os.environ["PATH"] )
os.environ["PATH"] += ":/usr/local/bin" 
print("## Addind gs to environ ##", os.environ["PATH"] )
#then the others import, and everything else
```

is that don't work try with one of this

```
os.environ["PATH"] += "Library/usr/local/bin" 
os.environ["PATH"] = "/usr/local/bin:" + os.environ["PATH"]
os.environ["PATH"] = "Library/usr/local/bin:" + os.environ["PATH"]
```

**EDIT 3**

as this solution work, a more automatic version of this can be something like this:

```
#this is the very first thing to do
import os, subprocess, shutil
#see is gs is avaible
if shutil.which("gs") is None:
   print("GhostScrip is not avaible, search for it")
   try:
      gs = subprocess.Popen(["which","gs"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      gs_path = gs.stdout.read()
      gs_path = gs_path.decode() if isinstance(gs_path,bytes) else gs_path
      print("GhostScrip found in",gs_path)
      os.environ["PATH"] += ":"+ os.path.dirname(gs_path)
   except Exception as e:
      raise Warning("GhostScrip not found, this program may fail")

del subprocess
del shutil

#then everything else
```

Comment: Maybe...I don't know. The `savefirst()` function works for the person who answered at the very bottom of the answer list, but it still does not work for me. I really don't know why...I tried my best, but it just is not working..._*sigh*

Comment: Maybe you can look at my latest edit and tell me whether or not what `brew doctor` is displaying is normal?

Comment: When I run `shutil.which("gs")`, it returns nothing.

Comment: then that is the root of all you problem, I think. Try puting the folder where gs is in the PATH environment variable and try againg

Comment: How would I do that? Or do I just copy and paste the `gs` folder to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5`? (I honestly do not know much about the Mac command line. I am WAY more proficient in Python).

Comment: If you mean moving/coping the files, no. I don't know how to do that in Mac, because I am from windows, but it must have some way of puting some other entry in that environment variable, [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mac+path+variable) for that, when you know how to do that put there the path of the original folder where your funcional `gs` is

Comment: I did this, and I know this because when I enter `echo $PATH` the directory with that `gs` folder shows up. However, even after that, entering `shutil.which("gs")` in Python IDLE returns nothing...

Comment: you close and reopen the the IDLE first? otherwise you will see no change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100721/discussion-between-copperfield-and-r-kap).

Comment: @R.Kap I put a more automatic version of my solution

Comment: Okay, I tried your automatic version, but the `FileNotFound` error occurs.

Comment: mmm, then try with `os.environ["PATH"] += ":" + gs_path`

Comment: then forget it, use the working one or try some other variant yourself because I can't test it to see if it work or no because our different OS...

Comment: Okay, I guess I will use the original, but I will keep on trying different variants of this. Thanks for your help though! :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing a dependency. Download [homebrew](http://brew.sh) and install ghostscript from that:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

...

`brew install ghostscript`

There are also options for it which may be obtained using `brew info ghostscript`:

```
--with-djvu
        Build drivers for DjVU file format
--with-x11
        Build with x11 support
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
```

But the default install is often the most-tested.

Comment: As you can see in my post, I have already installed ghostscript. However, I am now trying to install xquarts. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: Post the complete python source. My guess is that you need to specify the full path to gs in the call to it, as python has a different PATH than you think it does,

Comment: Python is apparently located in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. Is that an issue?

Comment: So how would I specify the full path to `gs` in my function?

Comment: Post your python script in your question and I'll have a look

Comment: It's a LONG script. And I already posted the `save` function. Do you *really* need the ENTIRE script?

Comment: Okay...look at Edit # 3 please

Comment: Were you able to get it?

Comment: You haven't posted the **complete** python script. What's so hard about editing your question, hitting CTRL-A on the editor window and CTRL-v here?

Comment: I did, look at Edit # 3. My Python script is too long to fit here. It goes over 30000 characters.

Comment: I did look at your script on Google Docs. There's no savefirst() function contained therein.

Comment: Yes there is, if you look close enough. (Hint: It's above the `save()` function and below the `clearbg()` function. To find these, first find `Options()`, then slowly scroll up. You'll find `savefirst()` and the other two functions)

Comment: Okay. Sorry if I sounded pushy. I did not mean to.

Comment: **Also, the `savefirst()` function is called by the button on the bottom of the window with a blank piece of paper and a '+' sign in front of the paper.**

Comment: Were you able to run it?

Comment: You're still coming across as demanding, I'm trying to figure out where the call to gs is and why it isn't finding it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't mean to. I'm just a Python loving teen with many hormones pumping around my body, so I am full of energy and enthusiasm. I guess it's natural then.

Comment: But you sound like a really nice guy. I like you. Thank you for helping me so far, as I really do appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, you need only learn to channel your energy into finding out why things aren't working instead of demanding answers from volunteers

Comment: Trust me, I really do try my best to solve the issue on my own. But since I am just starting out in this field and thus have just a small scope of understanding in it, sometimes I just have no choice.Now, considering that, coming to SO and asking questions is not just my chance to solve my issues, but to expand my horizons, to learn what I did not know before about this amazing field of computer science and the many languages that govern it. I hope you understand why I may do this then.

Comment: There is a difference between asking questions of volunteers and demanding they give you answers immediately. We're busy, we have other things to do, you need to understand that. Also, if I helped, would you be so kind as to upvote me?

Answer (score 0):

Could not replicate on 10.11.2 with homebrew, same python version, using XQuartz 2.7.8 (http://www.xquartz.org). Found this too (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1922974?tstart=0)

Comment: How would I find out if I have Xquarts already installed or not?

Comment: usually lives in /opt/x11, but it depends on how you installed it. theres an xQuartz application sitting in /opt/x11/bin for me. You can try a `locate xQuartz`

Comment: this also seems to suggest to use xQuartz with ghostscript http://forums.scribus.net/index.php?topic=1195.0

Comment: I have now successfully installed GhostScript (with x11) and it now works in Terminal (see Edit # 2). However, my initial issue is **still not fixed**. I keep on getting the same Python IDLE error whenever I run my program (shown in my post).

Comment: Ok, be wary though. It is not finished yet (I.e. I still need to update the docstring as it does not reflect the entire program yet). Therefore, just so you can test the `savefirst()` function, it is activated by the button at the bottom of the screen with the blank piece of paper on it and a plus sign in front of the paper. Just to clear up any confusion

Comment: I was able to successfully use your savefirst function. only modification i made was i added `from tkinter import filedialog`, and you don't need the redundant `+".jpg"`

Comment: also `hen` doesn't need to be a global so far as i can tell in your script so far

Comment: Yeah, I made it global for something else. Anyways, it works on your system? You were successfully able to save it without any errors?

Comment: yep no issues. I installed the image stuff with `pip install Image`

Comment: Oh, I see. I will try that in a few minutes and tell you how it went.

Comment: If your path is incorrect, you'll get the error above (i.e. if the save path is `/this/path/does/not/exist`). Maybe you can throw a check in to see if `hen` exists? `import os.path; assert(os.path.isdir(hen))`

Comment: Okay, I did that, but I get an `AssertionError`

Comment: Also, when I got rid of `assert(os.path.isdir(hen))` from my `savefirst()` function and then did `pip install Image`, I still keep on getting the error.

Comment: The assertion error would mean that the path you are saving to does not exist. Do a 'print(hen)' in that function, what's the output

Comment: Also, the point of my save function is for the user to be able to save the jpeg ANYWHERE they want. That being said, I am saving the JPEG to my Pictures folder (i.e. `/Users/MyName/Pictures`)

Comment: The output for `print(hen)` is `/Users/MyName/Pictures/Hello.jpg`

Comment: Apparently `hen` DOES exist then. It just isn't finding `'gs'` for some reason.

Comment: Yeah sorry, actually it will fail because its not a directory/the file doesn't exist until you save it

Comment: Well, I do save it in the window. However, even when I save it, I still get the error.

Comment: So then what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: I still cannot replicate this, I've confirmed that the source code of pillow is the same but it does not throw an error. The issue here is that the process output can't be piped through gs. Maybe you can try explicitly adding `gs` to your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: also whats the output of `which gs`. It wasn't installed correctly at first so maybe there is an issue

Comment: also, you do not need the ghostscript python package i.e. here is my pip freeze: `cycler==0.9.0
Django==1.9.1
matplotlib==1.5.0
numpy==1.10.1
pandas==0.17.0
Pillow==3.1.0
pyparsing==2.0.5
python-dateutil==2.4.2
pytz==2015.7
scipy==0.16.1
six==1.10.0
wheel==0.26.0`

Comment: I ran `which gs` and the output is `//anaconda/bin/gs`...hmm...it installed in anaconda for some reason.

Comment: I did not get the Python package. I just ran `brew install ghostscript` to get it. However, Homebrew installed it in the anaconda directory, but that is NOT where my Python is located. The problem is, I have not been able to uninstall anaconda as of yet.

Comment: remove anaconda from your path if you're not using it.

Comment: you probably now have several versions of python installed as well which is not advised

Comment: i'd remove anaconda/bin from your path, make sure gs is installed (if you use homebrew then both python and gs can be installed under /usr/local/bin) and try again

Comment: Do you know how I would remove anaconda from my path?

Comment: its probably been added to your .bash_rc

Comment: as a quick fix you can try doing `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}://anaconda/bin"` and running your script again

Comment: Okay, now `which gs` returns `/usr/local/bin/gs`, but I still get the same error in Python.

Comment: Apparently, when I run `brew doctor`, I get the warning: `Warning: python is symlinked to python3` Is that an issue, and probably why my script is not working? Also,      `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}://anaconda/bin"` really did nothing.

Comment: GhostScript with x11 also successfully runs when I type `gs` into the Terminal, but I am still getting the Python IDLE error.

Comment: no thats just telling you that python refers to python3 instead of python2

Comment: both python3 and gs are installed under /usr/local and the error is still occurring?

Comment: Yes. I even just checked. Both Python3.5 and `gs` are under the same directory (`usr/local/bin/`), and the error still occurs. Look at the image in my most recent edit for clarification.