# PIL Tkinter Canvas EPS to PNG conversion output file contains issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, save, python-imaging-library

So I have created the following save function for my turtle graphics program to allow the user to save the canvas as a .png file with its own file name:

```
def savefirst():
    cnv = getscreen().getcanvas() 
    ps = cnv.postscript(colormode = 'color')
    hen = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    print(hen)
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))
    im = im.resize((2560, 1600), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    quality_val = 95
    sharp = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(im)
    sharp.enhance(2.0).save(hen + '.png', 'PNG')
```

However, if the user were to set the background to a different color, in the output file (.png) **the background color *does not* appear**. Also, **the output image gets VERY rough around curves.** Below is what I mean, according to a screenshot of the canvas itself comparing it to the saved output:

Screen shot of Canvas itself:
[image: Canvas]

Saved Output:
[image: Saved Output]

**How would I fix these issues, preferably somehow using the Python Imaging Library?** If that is not possible, **is there ANY other way for me to save my canvas as a jpeg so that EVERYTHING comes out flawless (just as a screenshot, i.e. with ALL the colors and NO distortions)?** Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know about the background, but the text issue is normal with jpeg, check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBX8GFqt6GA)

Comment: @Copperfield Actually, this issue occurs even with .png files, so it is not just related to .jpeg filetypes.

Comment: my guess is that the background color isn't saved because the background isn't a canvas object. If you want to save the color, add a rectangle to the canvas that is the exact size of the canvas, and give it the color that you want.

Comment: @BryanOakley But won't that rectangle just be created over the current drawings?

Comment: @BryanOakley And also, how isn't the background color a canvas object, but a background IMAGE is?

Comment: the background is an attribute of the widget, not part of the drawing. An image is drawn on the canvas. As for the rectangle being over the drawing... Items are "stacked", so it can be behind all of the other items if you want.

Comment: As you do not provide the code where you set up the canvas I am left to guess that the canvas resolution is not the same as the screen resolution. You need to increase the canvas resolution if you want to get a higher resolution image (and thus a better quality image)