# No such file or directory: 'gs' linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, virtual-machine, ghostscript

I have a problem regarding using GhostScript to convert the ps file to JPG.

I have successfully got it to work in my Win7 machine, but for some reason it doesn't work in my Linux VM. I'm really not sure how to add the environment variables there(because that was needed in windows installation). Basically I'm testing it with the following code:

```
ps = cv.postscript(colormode='color')
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))
img.save("wut.jpg")
```

But when executing it, I get the following error:
[image]

But when I type in "gs" in the command line in Linux, it says that it is installed:
[image]

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: I guess this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564145/python-no-such-file-or-directory-gs-error-even-with-ghostscript-installed-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your shell, find the location of ghostscript with `which gs`.

Check that the path in python (`os.environ['PATH']`) contains the location of ghostscript.